# Trying to install IDLE2HTML on Windows 10, how can I append .txt file to .def file using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

The read me says:

> Copy IDLE2HTML.py to your the idlelib folder of your python
>   installation. Append the contents of 'config-extensions.txt' to your 
>   'config-extensions.def' file (also in the idlelib folder) and restart
>   IDLE.
>
> For more information on extending IDLE read 'config-main.def', 
>   'config-extensions.def' and 'extend.txt'

Here is the code I am supposed to append from the txt file to the def file:

```
[IDLE2HTML]
enable=1
[IDLE2HTML_bindings]
idle2html=
```

My attempts to search for an answer led me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file) that had this code:

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("appended text")
```

but I had a few questions:

1. Would that code work on a .def file or would only work for a .txt file
2. The text I need to append is 4 lines, would I just have to run it 4 times using each of the four times as an input?
3. Is there a way to append the .txt file directly on to the .def file?

Thanks in advance to any help I can get, I realize this is probably a very noob-y question but I am learning Python by following an online class and I have yet to learn how to work w/ reading and writing files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do this programmatically. What the installation instructions are actually saying is:

1.) Navigate to the folder where `idle.py` is saved. On Windows this should be at: `C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib` or something similar. If you're having a hard time finding it on Windows you can right click on it in the Start menu and navigate to the Shortcut tab - this should show you where it is located. If you're on another OS I'm sure a quick Google search can help you out.

2.) Copy the `IDLE2HTML.py` file that you downloaded to this folder

3.) Within this folder there should also be a file called `config-extensions.def`. You can open this with Notepad (or any other simple text editor - just use right-click and "Open with") and copy/paste those four lines onto the end of the file and save.

If all goes well you should see the new behavior once you restart IDLE.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much!!! 


  **You can open this with Notepad (or any other simple text editor**


I did not know this, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you can start IDLE, you can find the path to its directory as follows: on the top menu, click `File`, then `Open Module`. (The shortcut is Alt-M at least on Windows.)  Enter `idlelib`. The title bar of the editor window will contain `__init__.py - <path-to-idlelib>/__init__.py (x.y.z)`.